# How to show Next Post using current Id in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a WordPress theme. I made a grid structure shown below,

[image: Grid Structure]

It contains two rows, and every row has three columns. I want to show random posts from my WordPress database in this grid.

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="rst-mediagrid">
      <div class="div">
        <?php
        $args = array(
          'posts_per_page'   => 6,
          'offset'           => 0,
          'category'         => '2',
          'category_name'    => '',
          'orderby'          => 'date',
          'include'          => '',
          'exclude'          => '',
          'meta_key'         => '',
          'meta_value'       => '',
          'post_type'        => 'post',
          'post_mime_type'   => '',
          'post_parent'      => '',
          'author'    => '',
          'post_status'      => 'publish',
          'suppress_filters' => true 
        );

        global $post;
        $post = get_post($args);

        $next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'taxonomy_slug' ); 
        ?>          
        <div class="rst-col rst-col-50">
          <div class="rst-postpic">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); //latest post thumbnail ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php //endif; ?>

        <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
          <div class="rst-postpic rst-postvideo">       
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID); ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
          <div class="rst-postpic">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID); ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="div">
        <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
          <div class="rst-postpic">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
          <div class="rst-postpic rst-postvideo">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rst-col rst-col-50">
          <div class="rst-postpic">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code repeats the same image that I want to show thumbnails for in a perfect order, like the first row has three columns, and the first column has the latest image second column has image of previous post and third column has image of previous of previous mean 3rd post from latest post and second row also has same things.

If you have better suggestion kindly tell me.

Answer (score 1):

use this It does not need to use id of current post as argument. 
`<?php echo get_next_post(); ?>`

Comment: no dear its never working in my case you have any other suggestion ??

Comment: use `<?php $nextPost = get_next_post(true); $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(150,150) ); echo $nextthumbnail; ?>`

Comment: Can you try `<?php next_post_link('&laquo;&nbsp;%link','%title', TRUE); ?><br /><?php $nextPost = get_next_post(true); $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(150,150) ); echo $nextthumbnail; ?>`

Comment: i repeat this code in all div or declare only one time **$nextPos=get_next_post(true);**

Comment: I guess you have a single-page.php template . just add it after the loop. I hope It will work .I got this link just now https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-nextprevious-post-id-in-a-particular-loop?replies=2 I hope It will give you some idea.

Comment: dear you code is good it show next post only one time but after that it repeat the thumbnail

Comment: i am not using loop please see above code no loop in above code and this is my home page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91071/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-hafiz-usman-aftab).

Answer (score 0):

at last i found a solution of my question if some one else have same issue then use this

```
<?php 

      global $post;

      $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 9,'orderby'=>rand) );

      $posts = array();

         while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 

                    $items = array();

                   $items['link']=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
                   $items['Image'] = get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->the_post());
                  $items['LinkPost']=get_permalink($post->ID);               


                 $items['Title']=get_the_title($post->ID);
                 $items['PostTime']=get_the_time('M d,Y', $post->ID);


                array_push($posts, $items);


                 endwhile;
                  for($i = 1; $i< count($posts); $i++){


                                                ?>
                                                    <?php
                                                    if($i==1){
                                                    ?>
                        <div class="div">
                            <div class="rst-col rst-col-50">
                                <div class="rst-postpic">
                                                                        <a href="<?php echo $posts[$i]['LinkPost']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $posts[$i+1]['link']; ?>" alt="" style="height: 385px;width: 770px"/></a>

                                </div>
                                <div class="rst-postinfo">
                                    <a href="#"><span>Sport</span></a>
                                    <h6><a href="<?php echo $posts[$i]['LinkPost']; ?>"><?php echo $posts[$i]['Title']; ?></a></h6>
                                    <time><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo $posts[$i]['PostTime']; ?></time>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                        <?php //endif; ?>

                            <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
                                <div class="rst-postpic rst-postvideo">

                                    <a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+1]['LinkPost']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $posts[$i+2]['link']; ?>" alt="" style="height: 385px;width: 770px"/></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rst-postinfo">
                                    <a href="#"><span>Sport</span></a>
                                    <h6><a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+1]['LinkPost']; ?>"><?php echo $posts[$i+1]['Title']; ?></a></h6>
                                    <time><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo $posts[$i+1]['PostTime']; ?></time>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
                                <div class="rst-postpic">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+2]['LinkPost']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $posts[$i+3]['link']; ?>" alt="" style="height: 385px;width: 770px"/></a>

                                </div>
                                <div class="rst-postinfo">
                                    <a href="#"><span>Sport</span></a>
                                    <h6><a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+2]['LinkPost']; ?>"><?php echo $posts[$i+2]['Title']; ?></a></h6>
                                    <time><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo $posts[$i+2]['PostTime']; ?></time>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div><!-- end first row-->
                                                    <?php } //end if ?>
                                                <?php
                                                if($i == 2 ){
                                                ?>
                        <div class="div">
                            <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
                                <div class="rst-postpic">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $posts[$i]['LinkPost']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $posts[$i+1]['link']; ?>" alt="" style="height: 385px;width: 770px"/></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rst-postinfo">
                                    <a href="#"><span>Sport</span></a>
                                    <h6><a href="<?php echo $posts[$i]['LinkPost']; ?>"><?php echo $posts[$i]['Title']; ?></a></h6>
                                    <time><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo $posts[$i]['PostTime']; ?></time>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rst-col rst-col-25">
                                <div class="rst-postpic rst-postvideo">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+1]['LinkPost']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $posts[$i+2]['link']; ?>" alt="" style="height: 385px;width: 770px"/></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="rst-postinfo">
                                    <a href="#"><span>Sport</span></a>
                                    <h6><a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+1]['LinkPost']; ?>"><?php echo $posts[$i+1]['Title']; ?></a></h6>
                                    <time><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo $posts[$i+1]['PostTime']; ?></time>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rst-col rst-col-50">
                                <div class="rst-postpic">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+2]['LinkPost']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $posts[$i+3]['link']; ?>" alt="" style="height: 385px;width: 770px"/></a>

                                </div>
                                <div class="rst-postinfo">
                                    <a href="#"><span>Sport</span></a>
                                    <h6><a href="<?php echo $posts[$i+2]['LinkPost']; ?>"><?php echo $posts[$i+2]['Title']; ?></a></h6>
                                    <time><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo $posts[$i+2]['PostTime']; ?></time>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div><!--end second row-->
                                                     <?php
                                                }//end if

                                                }//end for loop ?>
```

if some have better suggestion kindly post you answer here and also any logical issue in my code then also tell me